# Sencha touch 2.3.1 --missing charts

Tags: charts, sencha-touch-2

I'm devloping a sencha touch app, the version I've downloaded (2.3.1.) has the chart, draw and fx src folders empty. I was unable to find how to configure the package to download or where to download the required sources.

Is it a licensing problem? I look all over the website but couldn't find an explanation of why it's missing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE:**

Since I answered this question I have created a Sencha Touch / ExtJS extension using NVD3 charts. You can get the extension here: https://github.com/woodenconsulting/OpenCharts-For-Sencha-Touch-and-ExtJS

---

You have to buy a license which can be done here: https://www.sencha.com/store/sencha-touch-bundle/

Alternatively, you can incorporate nvd3 charts. I have used them with several sencha applications. You can download nvd3 here: http://nvd3.org/

Here is an example of an easy BarChart using nvd3 in Sencha:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.BarChart',{
    extend: 'Ext.Component',

    xtype: 'barchart',

    config: {
        chartData:[],
        layout:'fit',
        height:'100%',
        width:'100%'
    },

    initialize: function(){
        // Init and add a bar chart
        nv.addGraph(Ext.bind(function(){
            var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart().x(function(d) { return d.label; }).y(function(d) { return d.value; }).staggerLabels(true).tooltips(false).showValues(true);
            d3.select(this.innerElement.dom).append('svg').datum(this.getChartData()).transition().duration(500).call(chart);

            nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

            this.chart = chart;

            return chart;
        },this));
    }
});
```

Then in your controller you can instantiate it like so:

```
var averageTimeChart = Ext.create('MyApp.view.BarChart', {
        chartData: [{
            key: 'Average Time Per Day',
            values: data
        }]
    });
```

Comment: @Jeff Wooden nvd3 supports touch events?